# Is it possible to determine if a pthread_t struct is unused?

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

Is it possible to determine if a pthread_t struct I have declared is unused? I have an array of pthread_t structs, and at the end of my program I call pthread_join() on each, but if some of them are never used I don't want to call pthread_join() on them. What's the best way to tell if a pthread_t struct has gone unused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pthread_t` object passed to `pthread_join()` must refer to a joinable thread. So you need to track this yourself - keep a flag alongside the pthread_t object to track whether it's used (maybe package the flag in a struct with the pthread_t).

Just keep in mind that in addition to not having used the `pthread_t` object yet, if you detach from or join the thread, you need to clear the flag as well (I'm not sure if this is an exhaustive list of when a `pthread_t` object becomes 'non-joinable'...).

Comment: And `pthread_t` is not necessarily a struct! It's an opaque type which could be `some_type *` or `unsigned int` for all you know. Only a fairly recent POSIX corrigendum (2004) removed the requirement that `pthread_t` be an arithmetic type, allowing it to be a structure.